# Infinite loop on Redux saga yield call using Axios with JWT tokens

Tags: redux, axios, redux-saga

I have been trying to obtain data using Axios through Redux-saga using Redux-toolkit & react. It appears that intercepting a saga call with a token gets redux-saga in an infinite loop? Or is it because of my watchers?

I have recently been learning how to program so my skills in all areas are not yet great, hope you dont mind the way the code is written as I have been following tutorials mostly.

On handleSubmit from a **Header.tsx** to **dispatch**

```js
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  dispatch(getCurrentUser());
};
```

my **rootSaga.tsx** includes all watcherSagas notices the dispatch for **getCurrentUser()**

```js
import { takeLatest } from "redux-saga/effects";
import {
  handleLogInUser,
  handleGetCurrentUser,
  handleSetCurrentUser,
} from "./handlers/user";
import {
  logInUser,
  getCurrentUser,
  setCurrentUser,
} from "../slices/user/userSlice";

export function* watcherSaga() {
  yield takeLatest(logInUser.type, handleLogInUser);
  yield takeLatest(getCurrentUser.type, handleGetCurrentUser);
  yield takeLatest(setCurrentUser.type, handleSetCurrentUser);
}
```

the watcher calls **handleGetCurrentUser** for the saga located in **user.tsx file in handler** folder:

```js
import { call, put } from "redux-saga/effects";
import { setCurrentUser } from "../../slices/user/userSlice";
import { requestLogInUser, requestGetCurrentUser } from "../requests/user";

export function* handleLogInUser(action) {
  try {
    console.log(action + "in handleLogInUser");
    yield call(requestLogInUser(action));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

export function* handleGetCurrentUser(action) {
  try {
    const response = yield call(requestGetCurrentUser);
    const userData = response;
    yield put(setCurrentUser({ ...userData }));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Which then uses yield call to **requestGetCurrentUser** which fires off the request to the following **user.tsx in requests** folder

```js
import axiosInstance from "../../../axios/Axios";

export function requestGetCurrentUser() {
  return axiosInstance.request({ method: "get", url: "/user/currentUser/" });
}
```

The response is given back and put in const userData, I consoleLog()'d the handler and discovered the following:

1. it will reach the handler successfully
2. go to the yield call
3. obtain the data successfully
4. return the data back to the handler
5. then it restarts the entire yield call again?

It also never makes it back to the userSlice in order to put the data.

**axiosInstance** in my **axios.tsx** file which includes the interceptor and gets the access_token and adds it to the header.

```js
import axios from "axios";

const baseURL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/";

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: baseURL,
  timeout: 5000,
  headers: {
    Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("access_token"),
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    accept: "application/json",
  },
});

axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
    return response;
  },
  async function (error) {
    const originalRequest = error.config;

            if (typeof error.response === "undefined") {
      alert(
        "A server/network error occurred. " +
          "Looks like CORS might be the problem. " +
          "Sorry about this - we will get it fixed shortly."
      );
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }

    if (
      error.response.status === 401 &&
      originalRequest.url === baseURL + "token/refresh/"
    ) {
      window.location.href = "/login/";
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }

    if (
      error.response.data.code === "token_not_valid" &&
      error.response.status === 401 &&
      error.response.statusText === "Unauthorized"
    ) {
      const refreshToken = localStorage.getItem("refresh_token");

      if (refreshToken) {
        const tokenParts = JSON.parse(atob(refreshToken.split(".")[1]));

        // exp date in token is expressed in seconds, while now() returns milliseconds:
        const now = Math.ceil(Date.now() / 1000);
        console.log(tokenParts.exp);

        if (tokenParts.exp > now) {
          return axiosInstance
            .post("/token/refresh/", {
              refresh: refreshToken,
            })
            .then((response) => {
              localStorage.setItem("access_token", response.data.access);
              localStorage.setItem("refresh_token", response.data.refresh);

              axiosInstance.defaults.headers["Authorization"] =
                "JWT " + response.data.access;
              originalRequest.headers["Authorization"] =
                "JWT " + response.data.access;

              return axiosInstance(originalRequest);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
              console.log(err);
            });
        } else {
          console.log("Refresh token is expired", tokenParts.exp, now);
          window.location.href = "/login/";
        }
      } else {
        console.log("Refresh token not available.");
        window.location.href = "/login/";
      }
    }

    // specific error handling done elsewhere
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

export default axiosInstance;
```

The **userSlice.tsx**

```js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState: {},
  reducers: {
    logInUser(state, action) {},
    getCurrentUser() {},
    setCurrentUser(state, action) {
      const userData = action.payload;
      console.log(userData + "we are now back in slice");
      return { ...state, ...userData };
    },
  },
});

export const { logInUser, getCurrentUser, setCurrentUser } = userSlice.actions;

export default userSlice.reducer;
```

I discovered that if I were to remove the authorization token it only fires off once and gets out of the infinite loop since it throws the unauthorised error.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Could you post your actions creators too ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for getting back so late, I managed to fix it a while ago by pure chance and I dont exactly understand why.

But I believe what fixed it were the following two things:

Changing the useEffect that dispatched the action and ensuring that the handler returned data that the useEffect was expecting to be updated.

In the handler I deconstructed the `userData` to `{ userData }` which I believe means that the data returned from the axios request is not the entire request but the actual returned data.

**my handler**

```
    export function* handleGetCurrentUser() {
  try {
    console.log("in request get user");
    const response = yield call(requestGetCurrentUser);
    const { data } = response;
    yield put(setCurrentUser({ ...data }));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

I forgot to add my useEffect to the post, which created the action.

my `useEffect` in the App.tsx would dispatch the call when the App was rendered for the first time. However because the returned data did not update what was expected it kept rerendering.

I cant exactly remember what my useEffect was but currently it is the following:

**my useEffect in App.tsx**

```
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getCurrentUser());
  }, [dispatch]);

  const user = useSelector((state) => state.user);
```